# What is HTTP's range-request size's relation to range start and end?

Tags: http

I am reading through [the official documentation on HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and it started mentioning Content-Range without much context so I looked up content-range and found some examples from mozilla such as [this discussing range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests). It makes sense at a high level, but the thing that does not make sense is why if you specify the range start and the range end in bytes which these examples seem to... then why do you need to specify the size and how can it be larger than the difference of the range end less the range start?

Any blog posts or visualizations would be great.

Comment: FWIW, the relevant published spec is RFC 7233.

Comment: I'll check that out - thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [RFC-7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.2):

"
For byte ranges, a sender SHOULD indicate the complete length of the
representation from which the range has been extracted, unless the
complete length is unknown or difficult to determine.  An asterisk
character ("*") in place of the complete-length indicates that the
representation length was unknown when the header field was
generated.
"